# Chartist.js: How to make chart axis not start at 0 but 10 off min value and 10 above max value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chartist.js

Is there a way to make the x axis on a chartist line graph to not start at 0 but 10 under the min and 10 above max value, currently no matter what the minimum number it always starts at 0?

[image: Chartist line graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally Chartist.js already does what you want. However, with options `high` and `low` you should be able to setup the borders of the diagram yourself, though this requires you to calculate those values for yourself:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line('#chart',
  {
    "labels": ["11/July", "12/July", "12/July", "13/July", "13/July"],
    "series": [[ 2150, 2152, 2147, 2148, 2149 ]],
  }, {
    high: 2160,
    low: 2140
  }
);
```

See also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agpu7wza/)